# Webpack builds files which are not imported

Tags: typescript, webpack, commonjs

Webpack is parsing files which I don't intend it to, and which I have not imported. As a result it throws errors about invalid imports in those files - errors which I do not wish to be concerned with during a build.

For example, from my latest build:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.e2e.ts
(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor'.
```

However the file is not imported anywhere, as shown from profiling. It is prefetched, but I don't have any prefetch plugins configured.

[image]

Webpack config:

`webpack.dev.js`:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ManifestRevisionPlugin = require('manifest-revision-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),

    new ManifestRevisionPlugin(helpers.root('dist', 'manifest.json'), {
      rootAssetPath: 'src'
    })
  ]
});
```

`webpack.common.js`:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'partials'),
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'partials'),
        loader: 'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + helpers.root('src') + '&prefix=static!html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw' // for angular2-template-loader
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      jquery: "jquery",
      _: "underscore",
      io: "socket.io-client"
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'RADREPORT_VERSION': JSON.stringify(helpers.loadFile('VERSION.txt'))
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to do with `ManifestRevisionPlugin` and `rootAssetPath`.

> It needs the `rootAssetPath` because I use it internally to walk that
>   path which detects assets that aren't currently listed under the `entry`
>   section of the webpack config.
>
> You might have let's say 1 javascript entry file and a few stylesheets
>   (your main app, some vendor sheets, etc.). This is fine and dandy but
>   what happens if you have 40 images? It would be unreasonable to have
>   to keep a list of images there but without it being listed there then
>   webpack really doesn't understand what to do with those files.
>
> To overcome that I walk the root path and ignore anything in
>   `ignorePaths`. For each file it finds, it internally calls
>   `webpack.PrefetchPlugin` on the file's path. This lets us tag the file
>   with the md5 or whatever you select in your webpack config (outside
>   the scope of this plugin) and have it emit the file.

https://github.com/nickjj/manifest-revision-webpack-plugin/issues/2#issuecomment-108029177